# Local WP site can't locate plugins or theme

Tags: plugins, themes

I'm trying to recreate a WP site on my computer but it's missing all the plugins and themes. The folders exist in the project and I can see the menu items in the dashboard, but when visiting the plugins page for the first time, it says "The plugin xxxxxxx has been deactivated due to an error: Plugin file does not exist". After refreshing the page it sets `active_plugins` to nothing in the options table and then displays "No plugins are currently available".

When visiting the themes page, it says "Error: The theme directory "xxxxxx" does not exist".

I've checked the permissions of the folders and they appear to be fine. Any idea how to fix it?